# Network manager not working on wifi and VPN

Tags: networking, network-manager, openvpn, bug-reporting

I'm reaching out here because even AI hasn't been helpful, and I'm hoping to find a solution.

I'll start from when the issue first appeared: I was installing OpenVPN and trying to configure it on my Lenovo IDEAPAD Pro 5i with Ubuntu 23.10 in dual boot. Initially, it seemed to work fine until I closed the monitor of my laptop. That's when the network started behaving strangely. When trying to add a new Wi-Fi network from the settings, and clicking on the SSID from the GUI, the Wi-Fi would disappear from the settings menu and then reappear seconds later without connecting, and it wouldn't even show the password input.

I began debugging the problem and found something related to dbus stating (when I restart the dbus service): iwlwifi wrt invalid buffer destination, or something along those lines.

I have tried the following:

- Removing OpenVPN (I don't think it's the real problem, but I tried it).
- Restarting NetworkManager and dbus.
- Using modprobe -r iwlwifi and then reloading it.
  Reinstalling linux-firmware, network-manager, and even dbus using sudo apt reinstall.
- Removing configuration files from NetworkManager, etc.
  But nothing seems to be working right now.

I know I have a non-LTS OS, but I hope to find a solution that doesn't require reinstalling the OS.

UPDATE:

Seems like i can connect and wireless drivers are working but I can´t manage settings, when i try to add a connection or a VPN even from the command line, it doesn´t work and i got this error

Error: Failed to add 'MyVPN' connection: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying